# Laravel searching with like

Tags: laravel, search

I want to search the whole table, the way I have it now is it searches a certain column in the table. How can I search everything from the table instead of a certain column in the table? Here is my code if you need to see it

```
    $userinput=$request->input('mywhat');

    $userinputt=$request->input('mywhere');

    $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $userinput));

    $strr = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $userinputt));


    $this->validate($request,array(
       $userinputt=>'nullable',
    ));

   $pro=Profile::Where('what','Like','%'.$str.'%')->Where(function ($query) use($strr, $userinputt) {
    $query->Where('location', 'LIKE', '%'.$userinputt.'%');
    })->inRandomOrder()->paginate(15);



    return view('layouts.reveal')->with('pro',$pro);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut with `like`,

You can try with [`MATCH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match):

```
$pro = Profile:whereRaw("MATCH(`name`, `foo`, `bar`) AGAINST ('$search')");
```

but
you can use [nicolaslopezj/searchable](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable) package it is easy and customizable and it also supports joins.

Comment: @Stephy501 If it helped you, Please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
$attributes = $profile->attributes;
$query = null;
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    if(!$query) {
        $query = Profile::where($attribute, 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
    } else {
        $query = $query->orWhere($attribute, 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
    }
}
$results = $query->get();
```

I do not recommend the above code for any production usage, but instead you can use already finished OS libraries like Searchy or others.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
$query = Profile::select('*');

foreach((new Profile)->attributesToArray() as $column)
{
  $query->where($column, 'like', "%$search_value%");
}

$models = $query->get();
```

Performance will become a problem as your data set grows, however. You may want to consider a solution such as [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout), which offers full text search on eloquent models.

This works by indexing the entire `toArray` form of a model as they are created/updated by default. You can leverage [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scout#queueing) for further performance benefits.

Then your searchs are simplified to:

```
$models = App\Model::search('Search Term')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone  for replying i will take everything into consideration  Thank you!!